# How can I fire, simulate or dispatch a click event on an OpenLayers map version 4.6.4?

Tags: openlayers

I have a map with a wfs layer loaded from geoserver, the features are loaded using the bbox strategy because there are over 60,000 of them. I have a simple click function that bring ups information on each feature

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
//random stuff to do here
  var pixel = evt.pixel;
  displayFeatureInfo(pixel); //function to get features and display the info
});
```

For my search bar I am using easyAutocomplete that searchs a json where each polygon has center coordinates. It finds the parcel, gets the lat and long and pans to it and zooms in just fine.

```
onChooseEvent: function(evt) {
    var parcelValue=$("#name").getSelectedItemData().parcel;
    document.getElementById('name').value=parcelValue;
    var selectedItemCoordX = $("#name").getSelectedItemData().long;
    var selectedItemCoordY = $("#name").getSelectedItemData().lat;
    var valcoordx=parseFloat(selectedItemCoordX);
    var valcoordy=parseFloat(selectedItemCoordY);
    var coords=[valcoordx, valcoordy];
    var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coords);
    map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform(coords, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
    map.getView().setZoom(19);

  }
```

How is it possible to either use the grabbed coordinates or the pixel and once you select, fire a click on the map so that once you move there the click event is fired and the popup will display without the user having to manually do it?

I have tried .trigger("click") on the map, viewport and canvas, I have also tried the .click() and triggerEvent() functions as well, but none of these even produce an error. I have also tried `map.dispatchEvent("click");` and this produces this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`

Comment: If you have the coordinates, can't you just use `overlay.setPosition(coordinate)` and display the popup? or if you prefer the pixel `getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinate)`?

Comment: It's not a popup, it's a fixed position sidebar that opens and that displays all the information on a property. So the click opens the sidebar on the relevant tab (different for a single property or for something like condos that have up to 80 owners) and also runs the function that grabs each feature at the given point. I already use `getPixelFromCoordinate(coords)` above, I'm just not doing anything with it besides checking it in the console to make sure it's not undefined or anything.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood this properly but all the click event does is find the feature at that pixel/coordinate and calls`displayFeatureInfo(pixel)`, correct? If you know the coordinates can't you use `getPixelFromCoordinate(coords)` and call the function inside`onChooseEvent`? I believe the `displayFeatureInfo` opens the sidebar.

Comment: Other possible solution is to find the feature, push it to select interaction and use `select.on('change', function() {})`

Comment: `var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {
  var features = [];
  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer){
    if(layer === layerWFS) {
      features.push(feature);
    }
  });`

Comment: The rest of the function is just is just grabbing attributes etc. I have tried using the whole function in my `onChoose` however it doesn't know what the pixel is that way, the click gives it the pixel information. I have tried using a similar function and manually setting the pixel to the variable pixel from the code in the question. I know you can trigger clicks or simulate them on html elements such as buttons or links, but maps are different. I'm looking for something that say's "Select here at this pixel and behave like a normal select interaction".

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: No unfortunately, the layers are only available internally right now, and all events happen on the layers.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone's still looking for an answer on this one, you can manually dispatch actions using the `dispatch` method on the Map object. The requisites for this (in this particular use case) would be to supply a both a type and a pixel coordinate. So, for example, to trigger a message:

```
map.on('click', ({ pixel }) => {
  console.debug(`Pixel ${pixel} was clicked`);
});
```

You could do something like this:

```
map.dispatchEvent({    //        
  type: 'click',
  pixel: [100, 100],
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, OpenLater 6.x + React 16 + Material UI 4.9.x. My OpenLayers map is in a Box Material UI component

Comment: `const _ = map?.getLayers().item(1).dispatchEvent(evt2)`
       . . . . 
`mymap.getLayers().item(1).on('click', (evt) => {...})`

Comment: As Box is kidnaping click event, i have to dispatch the event to its contained  map

Answer (score 0):

I never found a pretty answer for my problem but I did find a work around. I switched over to the autocomplete ui and added the search bar from [ol-ext](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext). I set the visibility on this bar to hidden. The ol-ext search bar easily searches any layer as long as the feature is loaded on the page. So I grab the feature id from my database with the jQuery autocomplete where I search my database, (it MUST be unique and MUST have zero fill) and I input that as the value in the ol-ext search bar programmatically. The jQuery bar zooms to my coordinates and I set a timeout to ensure that the features load and a timeout before programmatically selecting the result from ol-ext search bar to be sure it's updated. That then selects the correct parcel based on the id.

```
$(function() {
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        delay: 500,
        source: "searchData.php",
        minLength: 3,
        maxLength: 20,
        select: function(event,ui){ 
            idS=ui.item.id;
            var label=ui.item.label;
            var value=ui.item.value;
            $(".auto").val(value);
            var coordx=parseFloat(ui.item.long);
            var coordy=parseFloat(ui.item.lat);
            var coords=[coordx, coordy];
            map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform(coords, 'EPSG:4326', 
                'EPSG:3857'));
            map.getView().setZoom(18);
            $('div.ol-search').removeClass('ol-collapsed');
            setTimeout(function(){search.setInput(idS, search)},300);
            setTimeout(function(){$('ul.autocomplete li').trigger("click")},1000);
            $("#sidebar").addClass("collapsed");
        }
    })
});

var search=new ol.control.SearchFeature({
    source: wfsSource,
    property:'id',
    maxItems: 10
});
map.addControl(search);

search.on('select', function(e){    
    select.getFeatures().clear();
    select.getFeatures().push (e.search);
});
```

Like I said, it's not pretty but it totally works and no one even knows there is a second search bar. Version 2.0 of my site will have a better solution but this works for now.